# intellij idea cannot open current directory from terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, command-line, terminal, launcher

After an update of idea I had a weird message when trying to open the current folder as project:

`idea .`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/idea", line 137, in <module>start_new_instance(ide_args)
File "/usr/local/bin/idea", line 132, in start_new_instanceos.execv(RUN_PATH, [bin_file] + args)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Andriy Bazanov in this [post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000650650-open-project-folder-in-IDE-from-terminal?page=1#community_comment_115000534530) helped:

Recreating the Command-Line Launcher with idea itself:

1. `Tools` > `Create Command-Line Launcher ...`
2. Create Launcher Script at `/usr/local/bin/idea` > `OK`